# Storing char* gets clobbered somewhere along the way

Tags: c++, crash, memcpy

I have the following sequence of events:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    int seqNum;
    int ackNum;
    int pldSize;
    char* payload = (char*)malloc(DEFINED_SIZE);

    //buffer updated each loop, assume:  140hello!
    Packet::decap(buffer, seqNum, ackNum, pldSize, payload);
    Packet p = Packet(seqNum, ackNum, pldSize, payload);
    dataMap.insert(pair<int,struct Packet>(seqNum, p)); 
}

...
struct Packet
{
   Packet(int,int,int,char*);
   int seqNum;
   int ackNum;  
   int payloadSize;
   char* payload;

   char* encap();
   static void decap(char* datagram, int & seqn, int & ackn, int & bytes, char* pyld);
};

void
Packet::decap(char* datagram, int & seqn, int & ackn, int & bytes, char* pyld)
{
    memcpy(&seqn, datagram, sizeof(int));
    memcpy(&ackn, &datagram[4], sizeof(int));
    memcpy(&bytes, &datagram[8], sizeof(int));
    memcpy(pyld, &datagram[12], bytes);
}

Packet::Packet(int seq, int ack, int sz, char* pld)
{
    seqNum = seq;
    ackNum = ack;
    payloadSize = sz;
    memcpy(pld, &payload, sz);
}

...

map<int, struct Packet>::iterator dataIter = dataMap.begin();


while(dataIter != dataMap.end())
{
    outfile.write(dataIter->second.payload, dataIter->second.payloadSize); //<<< Crash
    dataIter++;
}
```

I can't figure out at which point I'm copying / clobbering my `payload` memory.. does anyone see anything right off that I'm missing?

Comment: It's hard to say without the intervening code, you might not be allocating enough space, or you might be deleting `payload` at some point before the last line.

Comment: In the constructor, look at the `memcpy`; it is suspicious. What is `payload` and why is that the source and `pld` the destination (which is the argument you passed in)?

Comment: May not be related, but shouldn't `memcpy(pld, &payload, sz)` be `memcpy(payload, pld, sz)` instead?

Comment: @StuartCarnie You are right; my mistake -- however, I guess the issue is deeper still. I get segfaults in the same spot.

Comment: So payload is a member variable; how is it defined?

Comment: I've updated my question, adding two loops which could be causing issues.. but I'm not sure.

Comment: @StuartCarnie I've updated the question with the struct definition.

Comment: the malloc in the loop is leaking and your intention in the `Packet` constructor is to copy `pld` into `payload`, however you have not allocated memory for `Packet::payload`. I'll need to construct a full answer rather than a comment

Comment: @StuartCarnie Ahhh, I think you're right! My question now becomes, how can I print this `char*`? With `dataIter->second.payload`, I get memory addresses written to the file:  `50c0 0402 0000 0000 c043 4a5f 6400 0000`

Comment: @StuartCarnie Am I actually storing the mem address here and not the actual data? Is that what's causing my data to be written to file as memory addresses?

Comment: You shouldn't be using memcpy at all and you're taking the address of the member variable `payload` in your `Packet` struct. Does your compiler support c++11?

Comment: @StuartCarnie It does not -- what do you mean I'm taking the address of `payload`? Where? (I've modified my constructor to be `memcpy(payload, &pld, sz);`)

Comment: you've never allocated memory for the `payload` pointer that you are attempting to copy into with `memcpy`, plus `&pld` is `char **`, which is a pointer to a pointer (i.e. a pointer to the pointer that points to the char buffer)...

Comment: @MrDuk it is always good to have some sanity checks in your code to check parameters in your functions, it may catch errors at an early stage. e.g. assert(sz>0);

Answer (score 0):

This line appears to be the culprit,

```
memcpy(pyld, &datagram[12], bytes);
```

Print the value of `bytes` before this line.

Comment: `pldSize` is passed by reference and is assigned by the line: `memcpy(&bytes, &datagram[8], sizeof(int));`  This is however a buffer overflow waiting to happen. `bytes` should be clamped or an error thrown if it exceeds the size of `pyld`

Answer (score 0):

C++11 example using automatic memory management:

```
typedef std::array<char, DEFINED_SIZE> packet_t;
typedef std::shared_ptr<packet_t> shared_packet_t;

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    int seqNum;
    int ackNum;
    int pldSize;
    // memory allocated here as new packet_t() but owned by shared_packet_t
    shared_packet_t payload(new packet_t());

    //buffer updated each loop, assume:  140hello!
    Packet::decap(buffer, seqNum, ackNum, pldSize, payload);

    // a second reference to packet_t exists in p
    Packet p(seqNum, ackNum, pldSize, payload);

    // a third reference to packet_t exists in a new copy of p that was created
    // when pair<> was constructed
    dataMap.insert(pair<int,struct Packet>(seqNum, p)); 

    // payload and p are auto released here, but a reference to packet_t
    // still exists via the reference to Packet in pair<> in the dataMap
}

struct Packet
{
   Packet(int,int,int,shared_packet_t);
   int seqNum;
   int ackNum;  
   int payloadSize;
   shared_packet_t payload;

   char* encap();
   static void decap(char* datagram, int & seqn, int & ackn, int & bytes, shared_packet_t pyld);
};

void
Packet::decap(char* datagram, int & seqn, int & ackn, int & bytes, shared_packet_t pyld)
{
    memcpy(&seqn, datagram, sizeof(int));
    memcpy(&ackn, &datagram[4], sizeof(int));
    memcpy(&bytes, &datagram[8], sizeof(int));
    memcpy(pyld->data(), &datagram[12], bytes);
}

Packet::Packet(int seq, int ack, int sz, shared_packet_t pld)
:seqNum(seq), ackNum(ack), payloadSize(sz), payload(pld)
{
}

...

map<int, struct Packet>::iterator dataIter = dataMap.begin();


while(dataIter != dataMap.end())
{
    outfile.write(dataIter->second.payload->data(), dataIter->second.payloadSize);
    dataIter++;
}
```

should be compiled with c++ -std=c++11

Answer (score -1):

`memcpy(pld, &payload, sz);`

I suspect you want this...

`payload = pld`